# Not able to receive inbound emails from yahoo

Tags: email, apex-email-service

I have created a email service and I have a inbound email class where I am inserting a contact when a email is received. When I send email from Gmail, rediffmail to my salesforce email service. I am receiving email to my salesforce env and contact is created but when the email is send from yahoo it is not received and no contact is generated In debug logs also the inbound class is not called. I may email service I have no mentioned any domain or email id.

Answer (score 5):

This is as per Yahoo's DMARC policy. I presume you are getting a response similar to this

> This message was created automatically by the mail system.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its 
>   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es)
>   failed:
>
> > > > testthis@yahoo.com (Undelivered): 554 5.7.9 Message not accepted for policy reasons. See
> > > >         http://postmaster.yahoo.com/errors/postmaster-28.html
>
> ------ This is a copy of the original message, including all headers. ------
>
> Return-Path:
>   
>   X-SFDC-Interface: internal  Received: from [10.237.9.131]
>   ([10.237.9.131:55852] helo=ops-mta2-2-was.ops.sfdc.net)  by
>   mx1-asg.mta.salesforce.com (envelope-from
>   )
>   (ecelerity 2.2.2.45 r()) with ESMTP  id A7/34-02119-68D77835; Thu, 29
>   May 2014 18:33:42 +0000  Received: from [10.236.71.27]
>   ([10.236.71.27:45272] helo=na14-app2-6-was.ops.sfdc.net)  by
>   mx4-was.mta.salesforce.com (envelope-from
>   )
>   (ecelerity 2.2.2.45 r()) with ESMTPS (cipher=AES256-SHA)  id
>   36/83-08380-68D77835; Thu, 29 May 2014 18:33:42 +0000  Received: from
>   [71.180.124.163] by na14.salesforce.com via HTTP; Thu, 29 May 2014
>   11:33:42 -0700  Date: Thu, 29 May 2014 18:33:42 +0000 (GMT)

You can find more information on these links

[Error "554 5.7.9: Message not accepted for policy reasons" when sending email to Yahoo](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail-for-desktop/SLN7253.html?impressions=true)

[Email service providers can't send to / from Yahoo addresses](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail/SLN24016.html?impressions=true)

Here's a [link](http://yahoomail.tumblr.com/post/82426900353/yahoo-dmarc-policy-change-what-should-senders-do) which explains how you can work around this issue.